# unable to launch internet explorer in TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am new in TestNG. This is my code which I tried in eclipse, but there is a problem occurring in launching internet explorer.

The error it is giving is
       *org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)*

This is the complete code....

```
package com.tcs.medmantra;
 import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Registration {
    WebDriver driver;
    WebElement element;
    WebElement element2;
    WebDriverWait waiter;
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void register_With_Cash() throws RowsExceededException, BiffException, WriteException, IOException 
      {
        driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("https://172.25.155.250/loginpage.aspx");
        //((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.resizeTo(1366, 768);");
        waiter = new WebDriverWait (driver, 40);
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtuname")).sendKeys("122337");
        driver.findElement(By.name("txtpwd")).sendKeys("Tcs!@345");
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnsubmit")).click();
        sleep(25000);



        //print URL
        String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println(url);

    }



    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {      
        File file = new File("D:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
        driver.quit();
    }



}
```

Comment: YOu would have to give much more data than that for someone to help you.  More code and error stacktrace?  Have you setup the IEDriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says you need set the protected mode same for all zones, either enabled or disabled. Preferred would be enabled. See [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/63141-internet-explorer-protected-mode-turn-off.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to include the path for InternetExplorerDriver.

```
File file = new File("C:/Selenium/iexploredriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Comment: i have already include the path for InternetExplorerDriver in my coding but the problem is still the same. have a look at the complete code i have reposted

Comment: Now i could figure out from your ErrorStacktrace that you did not turn off the protected mode in InternetExplorer. Let me know if you need help in doing the same.